# Simple way to pass selector $(this) to a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have several dynamically created `<div>`´s with data-attributes which I append to a another `<div>` like this:

```
var jobtypehtml = "";

for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {

    jobtypehtml += `<div class="jobtypeselect" data-jobtypechecked="0" onClick="check()"></div>`;

}

$('#jobtype').append(jobtypehtml);
```

On a click on a `<div>` the check function is called which looks like that:

```
function check(){

    alert($(this).getAttribute('data-jobtypechecked'));

}
```

As you see, I would like to get the data-attribute of the clicked `<div>`. I saw some solutions with .call and .apply, but that seems pretty complicated to me. Is there a more simple way to achive that?

**EDIT:**

```
function check(){

    alert($(this).data('jobtypechecked'));

}
```

The function above alerts "undefined".

Comment: You can use the function `$.data` as follow: `$(this).data('jobtypechecked')`

Comment: I tried that aswell, I forgot to mention. That alerts "undefined".

Comment: I would advice to create generic click handler and process all needed stuff there. Using such approach you will make your code much clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above $.data should resolve your problem. I've prepared a workind snippet for you:

```js
var jobtypehtml = "";

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    jobtypehtml += '<div class="jobtypeselect" data-jobtypechecked="'+i+'"></div>';
}

$(document).on('click', '.jobtypeselect', function(){
 console.log('Div clicked:' +  $(this).data('jobtypechecked'));
});

$('#jobtype').append(jobtypehtml);
```

```css
.jobtypeselect {
 width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
 border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='jobtype'>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that works, but it doesn´t if I set an onClick event in the <div>. It only works if I use the $(document).on('click'... eventhandler to call the function. Can you tell me why?

Comment: This is event-delegation (https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). Always this is a better way to create event handlers for dynamically created elements.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass `this` into your click function at the call site like so:

```
var jobtypehtml = "";

for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {

    jobtypehtml += `<div class="jobtypeselect" data-jobtypechecked="0" onClick="check(this)"></div>`;

}

$('#jobtype').append(jobtypehtml);


function check(elm){

    alert($(elm).getAttribute('data-jobtypechecked'));

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you [`event-delegation`](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for dynamically created elements.

```js
$('#jobtype').on('click', '.jobtypeselect', check);

var jobtypehtml = "";
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  jobtypehtml += `<div class="jobtypeselect" data-jobtypechecked="${i}">Ele from Stack</div>`;
}

$('#jobtype').append(jobtypehtml);

function check() {
  console.log($(this).data('jobtypechecked'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="jobtype"></div>
```

Comment: That looks pretty slick. :) But, are there any benefits to set the eventhandler to the $('#jobtype') rather than to the $('document')?

Comment: @stefanhalbeisen reduce the scope of where to look for.  This way, the js engine only check for elements inside of `jobtype` and avoid any clashes with other events in the document.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.jobtypeselect').on ("click", function(e) {
   alert ($(this).data("jobtypechecked"));
});
```

or:

```
$(document).on ("click", ".jobtypeselect", function(e) {
   alert ($(this).data("jobtypechecked"));
});
```

if you just want to use jQuery and take the onClick="check()" out of the markup.